# How can i force Internet explorer to shade the Input fields' placeholders

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am displaying placeholders for my input fields,but on IE the placeholders will be displayed as if they are manual text entered by the user, while on firefox & Chrome the placeholder will be displayed as shaded , so that the user can distinguish it from  manual entered text. so can anyone advice how i can shade the placeholders on IE ??
Thanks

Comment: On IE10 Win7 placeholder value is shadowed too, as i can see it

Answer (score 2):

For IE 10 you should be able to use this CSS selector:

```
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/2977133